# How to get a custom parameter value using PHP

Tags: php, get

I have my PHP page with URL : `http://www.example.com/out?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.it/sample-test` and I want a PHP function to print this: `Google.it`

I just need to print the domain name with capital letter and nothing else.

At the moment I use:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['redirect']; ?>
```

It gets the full URL contained in `redirect` but I want the domain name with capital letter.

Comment: `parse_url` function should help

Comment: You could use a regex depends, is `it` the only TLD you care about?

Comment: No, it was just a sample. I use .it .com .net etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/http:\/\/(?:.*?\.)?(.+?)\//", $_GET['redirect'], $matches);

echo ucfirst($matches[1]);
```

Here is the reg ex test:
https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/58

[image]

Comment: it works, but it gets just the first letter. example: G

Comment: I adjusted the regular expression it should work now

Comment: Try to print_r($matches). This works for me as you see in the regex101 link.

Comment: Added an images that shows that this works perfectly.

Comment: ok, it works but I see it gets subdomains too. Is it possible to get the domain only?

e.g. sample.example.com -> Example.com

At the moment it prints Sample.example.com

Comment: I updated the answer so that it matches any sub-domain

Comment: @GingerGirl It's not trivial to know where the subdomain ends. You can't just use the last two parts for the domain, because some countries have three parts, like `companyname.co.uk`. If you do some searching you should be able to find code that gets the domain part of a FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first decode the URL so you can use `parse_url` as mentioned in comments. Here is an option to go about it, with concept that www. will always be used...

1. decode url (`urldecode()`)
2. parse url to get just the host (`parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)`)
3. remove www. (`str_replace('www.','', $url)`)
4. uppercase the first letter of the string (`ucfirst()`)

In one line:
`ucfirst(str_replace('www.', '', parse_url(urldecode($_GET['redirect']), PHP_URL_HOST)));`

Comment: Sometimes URL has no www. What should I do?

Comment: If there's no `www`, `str_replace` will just return the original name.

Comment: Are you sure you need to call `urldecode`? PHP will do that automatically when it sets `$_GET['redirect']`.

Comment: @Barmar good point. I was using just a string variable called `$url` when testing so I had to include the `decode()`.